# Batch pasting data into excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a load of data which I need to process. I process it by pasting the raw data into a pre-made excel spreadsheet, trimming a few rows of zeros at the bottom of the processing (not pasted in) columns, and then running a macro to remove cells with 0 in them in column P.

Each spreadsheet takes 6 sets of raw data, each in a separate worksheet. The zero-removing macro takes a while so I would like to do the pasting as a separate job if I can.

I feel like this should be pretty simple but unfortunately I only have a very basic knowledge of code. My idea so far has been to try and use AutoHotKey to record a sequence to do it, but unfortunately it is clunky and hasn't worked so far because alt-tabbing is unreliable or some other issue.

**I would like to make a code which switches between windows, copying the data from one excel (tab delimited .txt) file into the main .xlsm document.**

I would manually save it and then open the next 6 datasets and a blank processing workbook.

Thanks for your time x

Edit: The datasets are always called a,a1,a2,b,b1,b2. They are always located in the same folder as the data processing spreadsheet. The data processing spreadsheet is always called [processor.xlsm]

Edit2: This is where I am:

```
Sub ImportData1()

'Prevent windows asking about saving clipboard data
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'select dataset a
Worksheets("SeqA Run1").Activate
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\a.txt"
ActiveSheet.Range("A4:I1000").Copy

Windows("Surge Test Data Analysis Importer.xlsm").Activate
Range("A7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
''Close dataset
Windows("a.txt").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close


'Select dataset a1
Worksheets("SeqA Run2").Activate
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\a1.txt"
ActiveSheet.Range("A4:I1000").Copy

Windows("Surge Test Data Analysis Importer.xlsm").Activate
Range("A7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
''Close dataset
Windows("a1.txt").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close

'(repeat several times)


'Re-enable windows prompts about clipboards etc

Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, did you find any answer useful here?

Comment: Yes - this started me on a journey which allowed me to develop strong and very useful skills with VBA/excel. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to switch between windows. You have to get references to the worksheets, and use the references. The first thing to do is record a macro, and then do whatever you would do, manually. Stop recording, and then start modifying the resulting macro.

Then, in your macro,

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set wb1 = Workbooks("<The name of your target Workbook>")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("<The name of your source Workbook>")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("<The name of your target> Worksheet")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("<The name of your source> Worksheet")
ws2.UsedRange.Copy
ws1.Paste
```

You may need to paste at a specific location in your Target.

Repeating requires looping (e.g., `For` ... `Next`). If you provide more info on your case, it would be helpful.

Remember that assigning to a variable of type Worksheet should be preceded by `Set`.

Comment: Hi there, see what you think of my edit. It is working well but yours is definitely more elegant!


With "UsedRange" does that select the whole area of the sheet? I would like to select only the data from row 4 downwards. It is always columns A-I but varies the amount of rows significantly.

Comment: `UsedRange` selects the bounding box of used range. Try: Open a new workbook, type 1 in cells `B2:B3`, and in the immediate window of the VBA editor (get it with <Alt>+F11) `Debug.Print activesheet.usedrange.address`. It's useful to tinker a bit in this way. Whether using `UsedRange` is ok for you depends on the contents of your Sheet.

Comment: You should avoid `Activate` or `Select` as much as possible. Replace `Worksheets("SeqA Run1").Activate` with `Set ws1 = Worksheets("SeqA Run1")`, `Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\a.txt"` with `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\a.txt"` and `ActiveSheet.Range("A4:I1000").Copy` with `ws1.Range("A4:I1000").Copy`. Work similarly in other cases. Hope you can work it out, and learn for future uses!